# Provide name for Entity Reference

Tags: 7, entities, views

Is there any way referenced entities could be named in a meaningful way?

Currently when I am creating a custom view and need to reference some entity, I have tens of entities that are named exactly the same: *Entity Referenced: Referenced Entity* (see the picture below).

In such setup there is no way to tell what the referenced entity is before using it. Is there any better way to have referenced entities on the system and still know what they are before using them?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can read a little bit more info in the Description text: `A bridge to the Content entity that is referenced via field_entityref` so if you're using different fields you can discern them by the field machine name.

Your theme seems to have the Description text hidden behind an icon. Can you see it when you click on the icon?